# Long running background process in PHP on windows machine

Tags: php, background-process, asynchronous

I have a script in PHP that uses Curl to hit a long list of URLs one by one and write the response to a file at the end, I want the list to be uploaded from a browser and do rest of the processing in background (without making the user to wait for response). I have already tried the following solutions -

```
    $command = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe ../background_process/subscribe_bg.php ".$file_temp_path;
    shell_exec(sprintf('%s > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &', $command));
```

This runs the script successfully, but makes the browser wait. (This will probably run in background on a Linux machine.)

```
    $command = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe ../background_process/subscribe_bg.php ".$file_temp_path;

    execInBackground($command);

    function execInBackground($cmd) { 
        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
            pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
        } 
        else { 
            exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
        } 
    }
```

I found this solution for windows machine, but doesn't work for me.The script does not execute at all.

Please suggest the best practice to run a long process(not very long ~30-40 Minutes) in background using PHP on a windows machine.

Comment: Thank you, sainiankit. This line:  pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); works for me. I am running PHP 5.3 on Windows 7.

Comment: `The script does not execute at all.` - Actually it would, it'd die though as soon as the parent process (the http request) did. A [background job implementation](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+background+job+queue&oq=php+background+job+queue) (or at a pinch [forking](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)) is too broad to be described on Stackoverflow - but that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Works perfectly for a windows machine, with all the output of the script written to the $response_file_path -

```
$command = $PHP_DIR." ../background_process/subscribe_bg.php -p=".$file_path_arg." >../sublogs/responses/".$file_response_path." 2>../sublogs/error_logs/err.txt";

execInBackground($command)

function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
        //Or the code for linux machine.
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I meant. It didn't work before, because your initial command wasn't redirecting output into a file ))) Thanks.

Comment: Oh yes ! Exactly, that made the browser to wait for the process to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should redirect output from your background process into another file. Since you are not redirecting it, PHP is waiting for it. Add '>' redirect to your command:

```
$command = "C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe ../background_process/subscribe_bg.php ".$file_temp_path . " > out.log ";
```

Good luck!
Danylo